# Strategy for not missing the flight on a 1-hour connection in Warsaw Chopin Airport

Tags: airport-transfer, warsaw, short-connections, waw

In about a month, I'll be flying with LOT, transferring in Warsaw Chopin Airport. I have 1 hour and 5 minutes if the flight is on time. The last time I flew with them (Tbilisi-Warsaw-London Heathrow), I had 1 hour and 10 minutes, but the flight from Tbilisi was delayed by almost 2 hours, so I ended up missing the connection. Luckily, there was another flight from Warsaw to London later that day, but I ended up arriving in London at about 6 pm instead of the expected 9 am.

This time I'm flying to Tbilisi, and if I miss my connection, the next flight is 24 hours later.

Having experienced the transfer once, I'm concerned that 1 hour may not be enough. On arrival, I'm likely to be bussed to the terminal, then go through passport control and personal security scan. Last time, from the the moment they opened the aircraft door to the time I got to the transfer desk, it took nearly 40 minutes.

Any suggestions to minimise the risk of missing the connecting flight at Warsaw Chopin airport?

Comment: Not everyone reads airportcode.  Can you expand them?

Comment: @Karlson Ok, done.

Comment: Sit at the front of the plane, then run on arrival?

Comment: @Gagravarr Yep, something like that.  I can't afford to miss the flight to Tbilisi, so I changed the London to Warsaw flight to an earlier one.  Now for the 12 hour layover in Warsaw... I'm sure I'll figure this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the normal transfer time is one hour (plus delay over 30 minutes), deduct time for taxiing and gate close time, actually you have less than 30 minutes for transit.

1. Prepare your passport and take out you computer/mobile before landing for faster security check.
2. Choose a seat as much towards the front as possible. Pack your stuff and prepare to leave before the flight landing to leave the flight early.
3. Have a look of [the terminal layout](http://www.flightstats.com/go/AirportTerminalMaps/airportTerminalMaps.do?airportCode=WAW) before departure to avoid getting lost
4. Tell the staff that you are in the airport when final call.
5. RUN!!!

PS:

I am not sure which flight you will be on board, but based on the information, I guess you are travelling LOT280 to Warsaw and LOT723 to Tbilisi. LOT 280 is often delayed for [over 30 minutes](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/lo280/), which means you are unable to take on the second flight. Prepare some Euros for food, and ask them for free hotel and [€400 compensation.](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm)

Comment: All in all, doesn't sound like much fun.  As I can't afford to miss the flight to Tbilisi (somebody is driving about 200 km to Tbilisi to meet me in the airport), I contacted the airline and it cost me the whole of £43 to change the London to Warsaw flight to an earlier one.  Now I'll just need to find what to do in Warsaw for 12 hours :)